# Настройка IDE eclipse, как посатвить кодировку по умолчанию?

Tags: ide, eclipse

Добрый день! Как настроить кодировку открываемых файлов по умолчанию в IDE Eclipse http://joxi.ru/2HTGU4wyTJCWLp4gNPU ? Каждый раз при открытии файла через RSE приходится вызывать контекстное меню щёлкая на файле, заходить в свойства и задавать кодировку cp1251, как настроить её по умолчанию?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во народ пошёл, даже такую простую вещь найти лень :)

[image]

Comment: не то чтобы лень я просто это искал в preference->remote system я ведь через RSE работаю, всмысле с FTP. )) спасибо!